# spark.createDataFrame () not working with Seq RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

CreateDataFrame takes 2 arguments , an rdd and schema.

my schema is like this

`val schemas= StructType(
Seq(
StructField("number",IntegerType,false),
StructField("notation", StringType,false)
)
)`

in one case i am able to create dataframe from RDD like below:

```
`val data1=Seq(Row(1,"one"),Row(2,"two"))

val rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data1)

val final_df= spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schemas)`
```

In other case like below .. i am not able to

```
`val data2=Seq((1,"one"),(2,"two"))

val rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data2)

val final_df= spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schemas)`
```

Whats wrong with data2 for not able to become a valid rdd for Dataframe?

but we can able to create dataframe using toDF() with data2 but not CreateDataFrame.

val data2_DF=Seq((1,"one"),(2,"two")).toDF("number", "notation")

Please help me understand this behaviour.

Is Row mandatory while creating dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, just do :

```
val final_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

Because your RDD is an RDD of `Tuple2` (which is a `Product`),  the schema is known at compile time, so you don't need to specify a schema

Comment: Thanks Roth!! may I know what is Product as referenced here ? and Row is not a product?

Comment: Product is an important trait in spark (and scala), with subclasses like tuples and case classes. It is important because Spark automatically provides Encoders for `Product`.  And no, `Row` is not a `Product`